# Sliding up from bottom using animate()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am  trying to make one `<div>` slide from bottom on another fixed `<div>` using the `animate()` method, but its not working,maybe I am doing it wrong.Here's the code:

HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id="back">This is fixed.</div>
 <div id="up">
  <p>This should slide.</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS part:

```
        #back
    {
        background:#CCCCCC;   
        width:200px;
        height:110px; 
    }

    p
    {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    p:hover
    {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    #up
    {
        background:#000000;
        opacity:0.8;
        width:200px;
        height:5px;
        position:absolute;
        color:#dedede;
    }
```

and finally the JS:

```
              $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#back').hover(function(){ 
            $('#up').animate({    
                height:'50px';
            },1000); 
        });
       });
```

Here's the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Nive00/tjp5m/8/)

Looked at a lot of other questions on SO as well but none of them worked for me.

UPDATE:Forgot to mention a minor thing that the sliding `<div>` should remain there for a while, so that I can click on the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

you mean like this? => http://jsfiddle.net/tjp5m/11/

```
    $('#back, #up').hover(function(){ 
            $('#up').stop().animate({    
                height:'50px',
                marginTop:'-50px'
            },1000); 
        },function(){
            $('#up').stop().animate({    
                height:'5px',
                marginTop:'0px'
            },1000); 
        });
```

**UPDATE 2:**

if I were you I would do this, this way => http://jsfiddle.net/tjp5m/12/

**much more efficient**

Comment: Yes! exactly! 1000 thanks! Just a minor thing. will you see the updated question? :)

Comment: you're welcome, glad it helped. BTW check out the new update (UPDATE 2).

Comment: Yeah! just checked, but can't see any difference except `marginTop:'-50px'`. mind telling?

Comment: plus the html, it is changed too, plus the jquery, removed the `#up` from the selector, this is much more efficient as I mentioned, because of the good coding and well positioning of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using only CSS, you want to animate the `max-height` property of `up` when `back` is hovered over. The benefit of doing it in CSS is it also maintains a clear separation of concerns (HTML for content, JS for functionality and CSS for presentation).

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjp5m/3/)

[(demo of sliding the other way)](http://jsfiddle.net/tjp5m/10/)

```
    #back {
        background:#CCCCCC;
        width:200px;
        height:110px;
    }
    p {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    p:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    #up {
        background:#000000;
        opacity:0.8;
        width:200px;
        max-height:5px; /* set height when slid up */
        position:absolute;
        color:#dedede;
        overflow:hidden; /* hide content when minimized */
        transition:max-height 1s ease-in; /* <--- set transition(animation) properties */
    }
    #back:hover + #up {
        max-height:50px;/* set height when slid down*/
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) but, but I want it to slide up from bottom. The fiddle you provided works perfectly fine just the sliding direction is opposite which can easily be done using jquery slideDown().

Answer (score 2):

You're using wrong syntax for [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#back').hover(function () {
         $('#up').animate({
             height: "50px"
         }, 1000);
     });
 });
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjp5m/5/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the code is atleast working now.(but not the way i wanted it to) +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, 50px should be a string:

```
$('#up').animate({    
     height:'50px'
},1000);
```

Edit: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tjp5m/7/

Update (see comments):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#back').hover(function(){ 
        $('#up').animate(function(){ // remove the function(), you're passing an object!
            height:50px; // it has to be '50px' and you have to remove ;
        },1000); 
    });

   });
```

Comment: you shouldn't pass a function into the animate, no arguments are allowed in `animate`

Comment: Yep, I shouldn't have copy&pasted that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. but that doesn't changes anything. still no luck. :(

Comment: You also have a ; after 50px - I'll update the answer.